# Error using \newcolumntype

Tags: tables, errors, columns

So, I have a table that I'm creating using tabularx. I want the last column to have a specified width but to be centered.
As I've seen in other questions I can put this in the preamble (that in my case is a separate document):

```
\newcolumntype{Ccp}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

However, when I compile the main file, even without using this new type of column, I get an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
}
l.35 \end{tabularx}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
```

When I comment the \newcolumntype in the preamble, it works fine. What's happening?

Comment: Have you tried `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`? A single letter should be used to denote a given column type. For sure, you should not use either `c` or `p` as letters, since these letters are already in use for two rather frequently used column types.

Comment: @Mico you are right! I don't have that error anymore. However, I'm getting another one. After begin table I've this: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c c c X C{25mm}} \toprule \Param. & Value & Units & Description & Source \\ \end{tabularx} \end{table}` The error I'm getting is: `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:​ not set up for use with LaTeX.` If instead of `C{25mm}` I wrote `c`, everything works just fine